# converting html data to json using python

Tags: python, html, json

I tried converting my html file data to json using below code

```
import html_to_json
import json
def htmltojson():
    with open("C:\Extraction\Sample.html", "r") as html_file:
        html = html_file.read()
        output_json = html_to_json.convert(html,capture_element_attributes=False,capture_element_values=True)
    with open('Final.json', 'w') as outfile:
        json.dump(output_json, outfile,indent=4)
        print(output_json)
```

The json i got contains html span and other tags altough i want only key and its values.

**Json output i got**

```
{
    "html": [
        {
            "head": [
                {
                    "meta": [
                        {},
                        {},
                        {},
                        {}
                    ],
                    "link": [
                        {},
                        {},
                        {},
                        {}
                    ],
                    "title": [
                        {
                            "_value": "252"
                        }
                    ],
                    "_values": [
                        "[if gte mso 9]><xml>\n <o:DocumentProperties>\n  <o:Author>Sharon Kaufmann</o:Author>\n  <o:Template>Normal</o:Template>\n  <o:LastAuthor>Aman Pawar</o:LastAuthor>\n  <o:Revision>2</o:Revision>\n  <o:TotalTime>339</o:TotalTime>\n  <o:LastPrinted>2019-11-07T16:41:00Z</o:LastPrinted>\n  <o:Created>2022-09-21T22:16:00Z</o:Created>\n  <o:LastSaved>2022-09-21T22:16:00Z</o:LastSaved>\n  <o:Pages>1</o:Pages>\n  <o:Words>1756</o:Words>\n  <o:Characters>10014</o:Characters>\n  <o:Company>AMS Inc</o:Company>\n  <o:Lines>83</o:Lines>\n  <o:Paragraphs>23</o:Paragraphs>\n  <o:CharactersWithSpaces>11747</o:CharactersWithSpaces>\n  <o:Version>16.00</o:Version>\n </o:DocumentProperties>\n <o:CustomDocumentProperties>\n  <o:_NewReviewCycle dt:dt=\"string\"></o:_NewReviewCycle>\n </o:CustomDocumentProperties>\n <o:OfficeDocumentSettings>\n  <o:RelyOnVML/>\n  <o:AllowPNG/>\n </o:OfficeDocumentSettings>\n</xml><![endif]",
                        "[if gte mso 9]><xml>\n <w:WordDocument>\n  <w:DocumentProtectionNotEnforced>ReadOnly</w:DocumentProtectionNotEnforced>\n  <w:TrackMoves/>\n  <w:TrackFormatting/>\n  <w:DoNotHyphenateCaps/>\n  <w:PunctuationKerning/>\n  <w:DrawingGridHorizontalSpacing>5 pt</w:DrawingGridHorizontalSpacing>\n  <w:DrawingGridVerticalSpacing>6 pt</w:DrawingGridVerticalSpacing>\n  <w:DisplayHorizontalDrawingGridEvery>0</w:DisplayHorizontalDrawingGridEvery>\n  <w:DisplayVerticalDrawingGridEvery>3</w:DisplayVerticalDrawingGridEvery>\n  <w:ValidateAgainstSchemas/>\n  <w:SaveIfXMLInvalid>false</w:SaveIfXMLInvalid>\n  <w:IgnoreMixedContent>false</w:IgnoreMixedContent>\n  <w:AlwaysShowPlaceholderText>false</w:AlwaysShowPlaceholderText>\n  <w:DoNotPromoteQF/>\n  <w:LidThemeOther>EN-US</w:LidThemeOther>\n  <w:LidThemeAsian>X-NONE</w:LidThemeAsian>\n  <w:LidThemeComplexScript>AR-SA</w:LidThemeComplexScript>\n  <w:Compatibility>\n   <w:BreakWrappedTables/>\n   <w:SnapToGridInCell/>\n   <w:WrapTextWithPunct/>\n   <w:UseAsianBreakRules/>\n   <w:DontGrowAutofit/>\n   <w:SplitPgBreakAndParaMark/>\n   <w:EnableOpenTypeKerning/>\n   <w:DontFlipMirrorIndents/>\n   <w:OverrideTableStyleHps/>\n  </w:Compatibility>\n  <m:mathPr>\n   <m:mathFont m:val=\"Cambria Math\"/>\n   <m:brkBin m:val=\"before\"/>\n   <m:brkBinSub m:val=\"&#45;-\"/>\n   <m:smallFrac m:val=\"off\"/>\n   <m:dispDef/>\n   <m:lMargin m:val=\"0\"/>\n   <m:rMargin m:val=\"0\"/>\n   <m:defJc m:val=\"centerGroup\"/>\n   <m:wrapIndent m:val=\"1440\"/>\n   <m:intLim m:val=\"subSup\"/>\n   <m:naryLim m:val=\"undOvr\"/>\n  </m:mathPr></w:WordDocument>\n</xml><![endif]",],
            "body": [
                {
                    "div": [
                        {
                            "p": [
                                {
                                    "a": [
                                        {},
                                        {},
                                        {
                                            "span": [
                                                {
                                                    "span": [
                                                        {
                                                            "span": [
                                                                {
                                                                    "_value": "Performance Work Statement"
                                                                }
                                                            ]
                                                        }
                                                    ]
                                                }
                                            ]
                                        }
                                    ]
                                },
                                {
                                    "span": [
                                        {
                                            "span": [
                                                {
                                                    "span": [
                                                        {
                                                            "span": [
                                                                {
                                                                    "_value": "UNITED STATES NAVAL ACADEMY (USNA)"
                                                                }
                                                            ]
                                                        }
                                                    ]
                                                }
                                            ]
                                        }
                                    ]
                                },
```

The expected output is something of the form

Example expected format

[
{
"key": "1",
"value": ""
"child":[]
},
{
"key": "2",
"value": ""
"child":[
{
"key": "2.1",
"value": ""
"child":[]
},
{
"key": "2.2",
"value": ""
"child":[]
}
]
},
{
"key": "3",
"value": ""
"child":[
{
"key": "2.1",
"value": ""
"child":[
{
"key": "2.1.1",
"value": ""
"child":[]
}
]
}
]
},
]

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like this? Just simply look up the element you are looking for?
https://www.w3schools.com/python/gloss_python_json_parse.asp

The python docs might help as well...
https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html

May I ask why you want to encode HTML to JSON?

Comment: Actually since the data of the files may vary so can't specify the attributes but if there is any flag I can tweak while dumping into json please tell.   For your second question it is a task provided to me and i have to provide the person with json of the html which he will use.

Comment: Please try this: 

Install the required module :
pip install xmltojson

```with open("sample.html", "r") as html_file:
    html = html_file.read()
    json_ = xmltojson.parse(html)
      
with open("data.json", "w") as file:
    json.dump(json_, file)
      
print(json_)```

Comment: I already tried it, It will give error because it requires XML file and I want to convert HTML to JSON
 File "C:\Extraction\Doc_Extract\functions.py", line 21, in htmltojson
    json_ = xmltojson.parse(html)
  File "C:\Extraction\Exenv\lib\site-packages\xmltojson\__init__.py", line 84, in parse
    return json.dumps(xmltodict.parse(xml_string))
  File "C:\Extraction\Exenv\lib\site-packages\xmltodict.py", line 327, in parse
    parser.Parse(xml_input, True)
xml.parsers.expat.ExpatError: not well-formed (invalid token): line 9, column 17

Answer (score 0):

**Well if anyone else wants a solution I solved it using below logic**

```
from html_to_draftjs import html_to_draftjs
import bleach,json
from bleach.css_sanitizer import CSSSanitizer

def htmltodraftjson():
    with open("WorkStatement.html", "r") as html_file:
        html = html_file.read()
        
        css_sanitizer = CSSSanitizer(allowed_css_properties=["color", "font-weight"])
        output_json = html_to_draftjs(bleach.clean(html,tags=['div', 'p', 'ul', 'ol', 'blockquote', 'h1', 'h2', 'h3', 'h4', 'h5', 'h6', 'strong', 'b', 'em', 'i', 'img', 'a', 'br'], strip=True))
    with open('WorkStatement.json', 'w') as outfile:
        json.dump(output_json, outfile,indent=4)
        print(output_json)
```